# rails Session :cookie_store set expiration per basis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need a session to stay around for 30 days (using rails 3.2, cookie store).

I'd like **not to** set a global config in config.session_store, but pass it as on option when the session variable is set, similar to how you can set an expiration on a cookie.

Is this possible?

If not, i'm planning to globally set an expiration of 30 days to all sessions, and use a date variable in a session var to do comparison/destroy if needed (but i'd rather not muck around).

Answer (score 0):

If you use cookies instead you can do it like so:

```
cookies[:foo] = { :value => "bar", :expires => 4.weeks.from_now }
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html for more information.

I am not aware of a way to have a variable session expiry, you will probably have to do it manually.

Something like:

```
def auth
  if session[:foo]
    reset_session if session[:last_seen] > 30.days.ago
    session[:last_seen] = Time.now
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, cookies are less safe IMHO, but it looks like I might have to use a cookie or roll my own solution with a global expiration.

Comment: Yea I agree with you completely.  Roll your own and serialise any keys etc that you use.